# How to insert json array data in postgres using python

Tags: python, arrays, json, postgresql

[{"foo":"data1"},{"foo":"data2"}]

```
create table jsonData (
id serial primary key,
data json []
)
```

```
query = ''' INSERT into jsonData (id,data) VALUES (%s,%s) '''
values = (id,data)
db.insertQuery(query, values)
```

i cant insert json[] data into jsonData

Comment: How are you connecting to the database?

Comment: i connected to the database. but cant insert json[] data